# Dynamical passing parameters to a function in Python

Tags: python, parameters, parameter-passing

I want to write a code that will check a dictionary for a key and if exist to set it to a function as a parameter.

```
def myFunction(*args, **kwargs):
    # do stuffs
    if('name' in kwargs):
        thisTitle = kwargs.pop('name')        

    print(thisTitle)
    ...
    return thisTitle

t = {}

if 'name' in t.keys() 
    and 'param1' in t.keys() 
    and 'param2' in t.keys():

    res = myFunction(name      = t['name'], 
                     myparam1  = t['param1'],
                     secondPar = t['param2'])

elif 'name' in t.keys() 
    and 'param1' in t.keys():

    res = myFunction(name=t['name'], 
                     myparam1=t[param1])

elif 'name' in t.keys():
    res = myFunction(name=t['name'])
```

What if I had 10 parameters? There must be a better way.

Comment: It appears you're aware of the `**kwargs` syntax, so maybe read this http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html and loop over the dictionary inside your function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
def myFunction(*args, **kwargs):
    # do stuffs
    if('name' in kwargs):
        thisTitle = kwargs.pop('name')

    print(thisTitle)

    if('param1' in kwargs):
        print(kwargs['param1'])

    if('param2' in kwargs):
        print(kwargs['param2'])
    # ...
    return thisTitle


t = {'name': "same_name"}

myFunction(**t)

t = {'name': 'same_name',
     'param1': 'val1',
     'param2': 'val2'}

myFunction(**t)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 stack.py 
same_name
same_name
val1
val2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest using the `default` argument on `pop` rather than checking for existence: `thisTitle = kwargs.pop('name', default)`; so you don't do both a `in` and a `pop`.

```
if('name' in kwargs):
    thisTitle = kwargs.pop('name')
```

Becomes:

```
thisTitle = kwargs.pop('name', None)
```

It might be better to use `get` rather than `pop` unless removing the key from the dictionary is an required effect:

```
thisTitle = kwargs.get('name', None)
```

Your function then would return `None` rather than producing a `NameError` when the `name` keyword argument is not provided.

Comment: Thanks @Dan D, very useful tip !! I was setting a default value always just before `if`